# binary addition / truth table?

Tags: adder, binary, truth-table

I'm trying to understand how binary addition works.
If I understand it correctly, with two variables e.g. `x` and `y` you add a third one called `c_i`. On the other side, you add the `sum` and `c_o`.

The rules as far as I understood them: If you have two 1's, you carry 1 out and the result is 0.

Here is what confuses me:

1) In normal addition, you would carry in the 1 you carry out to the next line. Why don't we do this here, and therefore, what happens to the carry outs?

2) why is the carry in an "input" of its own, shouldn't it be just `x` and `y` since the carry ins/outs usually belong to one operation distinct from the values we use?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: it operates exactly the same way as in grade school  with pencil and paper  add 9999 and 1001, most of the columns are three values being added together the carry out of one column is the carry in of the next.  the only difference is that with binary it is simpler because there are only two numbers 0 and 1 not 10.  If you were able to add 99999 and 10001 in grade school decimal with pencil and paper you can add binary numbers as well.  Understand that in grade school there were a lot of implied zeros we didnt talk about in logic they need to be talked about.

Comment: Try drawing the truth table for ordinary decimal 'schoolbook' addition, with the carry in and carry out shown explicitly, for a single digit. Then use this when you add some multi-digit decimal numbers with pencil and paper. The use pattern is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what happens to the carry outs?

You can combine *n* full adder circuits to make an adder for *n*-bit numbers. When you do this, you connect the carry-out from each adder to the carry ins of the adder for the next most significant bit.

Here's an example adding 2 3-bit numbers, X = A + B:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdMY3N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> why is the carry in an "input" of its own, shouldn't it be just x and y since the carry ins/outs usually belong to one operation distinct from the values we use?

It's more efficient to just calculate the sum of 3 bits in one operation than to add `x` and `y`, and then add `cin` in a 2nd step.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think I really understand the first part though. They connect to the next most significant bit? Would you care to elaborate? Since if you look at A = 1, B = 0. Cin = 0. Shouldn't it add the carry out of the last line meaning the result should be 0 and carry in  is 1 again. But in reality, the result is 1, and carry 0.

Comment: @user472288, suppose A is a 3 bit number made up of A0, A1, and A2. Then A1 is the next most significant bit in A after A0.

Comment: @user472288, also, it sounds like you're thinking of adding multi-bit numbers in a serial operation (using one clock cycle to calculate each bit of the result), where the rest of us are talking about doing it as a parallel operation (calculating several bits of the result in a single operation). Either way is possible. For serial, you'd store the carry out when calculating the 0th bit and use it as the carry in for summing the 1st bit, and so on.

Comment: Thank you photon!

Answer (score 1):

You do!

That C_in is your "carry in" for that bit, and that "carry out" goes to the next bit's cin.

Comment: But, when you look at A = 1, B = 0 and Cin = 0, and you consider that the last line had a carry out of 1, should this not result in 1 + 1 meaning 0 again and carry out of 1?

Comment: @user472288: If you add two 1 bit numbers, the result can be a two bit nuumber, so 1 + 1 = 10.  If you are doing multi-bit addition, then 001 + 001 = 010 .  The carry from the least significant bit is added to the second bit - same as decimal addition, where 6 + 6 = 12.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure I understand your confusion, You add the inputs (x,y) and carry in (c_in) and produce a sum. The upper bit of the sum now becomes the carry (c_out).
2. C_in is infact an input of its own. Its named so because this addition described in the truth table is just a part of multi-bit summation. Here's an example:

$$
x_3x_2x_1\\
y_3y_2y_1\\
----\\
s_3s_2s_1
$$

So, first step is to add \$x_1 + y_1\$ which produces \$s_1 and c_1\$
now in second step add \$x_2 + y_2 + c_1\$ which gives \$s_2 and c_2\$
So on..

Answer (score 0):

binary math, no different from decimal math in grade school

```
  11111
+ 10001
=======
```

one plus one is 0b10, or zero carry the one.

```
     1
  11111
+ 10001
=======
      0
```

one plus one plus zero is zero carry the one.

```
    11
  11111
+ 10001
=======
     00
```

you can finish it from there the carry out of one column is the carry in of the next...just like paper and pencil math from grade school.